# Error:Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've an error in log:

> Error:Content is not allowed in prolog

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem/error. I have searched for the solution but couldn't find.

Comment: Based on the screenshot, your file is an XML file. `/**` is not the syntax for XML comments. Get rid of that comment.

Comment: when i run the app it automatically creates it.

Comment: i have facing same issue have you got solution?

Comment: Yes @NikunjParadva. I move to web development :)

Answer (score 1):

in xml files we don't use `/* */` for comments.
use
`<!--
  comment...
 -->`

Comment: when i run the app it automatically creates it.

Answer (score 1):

**colors.xml** is an XML file for Android app colors. It should like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#A4C639</color>

  ...

  <color name="colorSemiTransparent">#15000000</color>
</resources>
```

The error could be happened because of **`accidentally copy paste code`**, **`bugs`**, or **`Windows crash`**.

From my experience, the problem arise a couple times when Windows 10 crash.